# the given data type enum() contains errors mysql

Tags: mysql, enums

I was using the data type enum() but I got this error in mysql workbench 
[image]

Comment: Enum needs a list of values, how exactly are you passing it

Comment: Did you try to define an ENUM column with no elements? You need at least one.

Comment: cuz I am doing this in the setting not coding. there are 2 ways to set up enum(),one is by coding eg: Status ENUM('Yes','No) NOT NULL. I am doing it in the second way by using the settings. is there a way I can do it in the settings ?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the exact statement you're running? Also remember that text, not screenshots, is the best way to represent textual data. Images can't be searched, copy-pasted or run as code.

Answer (score 6):

Each value must be quoted between single quotes, and they must be separated with commas. For example:

```
ENUM('Value1','Value2','Value3')
```